# newaliases.postfix hangs

Tags: postfix

... related to a **[previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/47348/postfix-mailserver-fails-to-start-on-centos5-2)**  about trouble running postfix on Centos 5.2(Final)

Looks like postfix relies on `aliases.db` which is built by `newaliases.postfix` command

When I run `newaliases.postfix` it just hangs indefinitely.
I have found **[some tips](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Fedora/2005-02/0366.html)**, but they weren't helpful (I've changed /etc/hosts and /etc/sysconfig/network accordingly to no effect)

Running `strace newaliases.postfix` shows this

```
...
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x2b9bb210c000, 4096)            = 0
read(0,  <unfinished ...>
```

Apparently it's trying to read from standard input but never gets any input.

Am I supposed to feed something to newaliases?

When I try `newaliases.postfix < /etc/aliases` I get

```
newaliases.postfix: fatal: Recipient addresses must be specified on \
the command line or via the -t option
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to specify newaliases.postfix, it should just be `newaliases` - but then again, you didn't tell me if you are on FreeBSD, Linux, OS X, or ?  What are you running?

Just the command by itself should digest the file.  If it's hanging on the digest then something is horked.

EDIT:

Ok, you have `/etc/aliases.db` now, but postfix is failing to start on CentOS.

Try this (as root):

```
yum upgrade postfix
service postfix restart ; tail -f /var/log/maillog
```

When postfix fails to start, it should dump out an error message at the end of the log, and the `tail` command will show that message for you.

Comment: it's centos 5.2

Comment: well that made some difference I am cautiously optimistic :)

Comment: now I have aliases.db, but postfix still does not start

Answer (score 3):

you have to put this on console and choose the right MTA (postfix in this case)

```
alternatives --config mta
```

then run

```
newaliases
```

this worked for me

Comment: For the record: I've just installed a completely fresh Centos 6.2 with only postfix installed.  `alternatives --config mta` only had 1 option which was already selected, but selecting it again caused a /usr/bin/newaliases to be created.  This seems to be a symlink via the /etc/alternatives/mta-newaliases link to /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix, yet the two behave differently.  strace shows newaliases.postfix stops when it reads on stdin (`read(0, "`) .. newaliases doesn't read on stdin, it just seems to open /etc/passwd a few times then complete normally.

Answer (score 0):

Having exactly the same problem, newaliases.postfix hanging, strace the same.
CentOs v7.9.2009
Postfix v2.10.1
Read main.cf :

```
# If you change the alias database, run "postalias /etc/aliases" (or
# wherever your system stores the mail alias file), or simply run
# "newaliases" to build the necessary DBM or DB file.
```

And this command is working for me (aliases.db updating):
`postalias /etc/aliases`